# Replacing 'i' with 'I' using Emacs ispell

Tags: emacs, ispell

I use [ispell](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Spelling.html) to do spell-checking, but it does not replace the word 'i' with 'I'.

Comment: As far as I can see, `aspell`, which is an advanced ispell that Emacs
can use as backed, recognizes all single letter words as correct,
even if they aren't in the dictionary.
So you should either request some help on `aspell` mailing list,
or use some specific elisp code to overcome this limitation.

Answer (score 2):

With the following code flyspell at least shows such misspellings. The list is to be extended.

```
(defvar flyspell-wrong-one-letters '("i"))

(defadvice flyspell-word (before one-letter activate)
  "Check one-letter words"
  (when (and
     (if following (looking-at "\\<[[:alpha:]]\\>")
       (looking-back "\\<[[:alpha:]]\\>"))
     (member (match-string 0) flyspell-wrong-one-letters))
    (setq known-misspelling t)))
```

I just looked into flyspell not into ispell yet. I know that this is not really a solution for you... Sorry.